# A program or filter that can read document sizes and print accordingly

Tags: pdf, adobe, acrobat

I have a very specific request about printing PDFs.

What I have is 294 documents that need to be printed. Usually what we do if they are all 8.5x11 or 11x17 is use the "Choose paper size by PDF page size" option, which will print on those sizes of paper respectively.

In this case, I have documents that are Letter, A4, A3, 11x17, 24x36, etc.

All of the regular-size documents (9x12 and below) would get printed on letter, while everything greater than 9x12 would get printed on 11x17.

Instead of opening each file individually and switching between the two page sizes constantly, I was wondering if there is a program or filter that could go through the document, check the sizes, and then print accordingly.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You could set up an Action in Acrobat, running a JavaScript which evaluates the cropbox dimensions for every page of the document, and then sets the printParams accordingly, and finally prints using the printParams.

The "boxes" dimensions are also available to the (limited) scripting capabilities of the application (on Mac, using Applescript), which would allow to set up a control file you could run.